# Nexmo api for .Net

Tags: c#, vonage

I am using the nexmo api for .NET to send verification code to given phone which gives me the following error

> The underlying connection was closed

My code is as follows

```
public bool PhoneVerfication(string PhoneNumber, long userId)
        {
            try
            {
                long? _cellPhone = Convert.ToInt64(PhoneNumber);
                var _util = new utilMessageSender();
                _util.SendVerificationCode(PhoneNumber);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

  public utilMessageSender()
        {
            client = new Client(creds: new Credentials
            {
                ApiKey = "********",
                ApiSecret = "**************",
                ApplicationId = "*********-****-****-****-***********",
                ApplicationKey = "**************"
            });
        }

 public void SendVerificationCode(string phoneNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = client.NumberVerify.Verify(new NumberVerify.VerifyRequest
                {
                    number = phoneNumber,
                    brand = "Offey-app"
                });
                RequestId = result.request_id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I am using this API for the first time it worked very fine and sent verification code to different phone numbers but I don't know what happened as now it's not working.

Comment: `try...catch...{ return false; }` masks all your errors, thus never helping you discover the real error. Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion :) I always look for better code

Comment: How to check TLS v SDK i installed using nuget packages